# Can an old bitcoin rig mine XVG?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, asic

I have an old block erupter, used to mine BTC with on Slush's pool.
To operate it, I had to download their mining proxy onto another computer on my home network and configure the ASIC so it would point to my computer's IP address.
Is there any way to configure the block erupter to mine XVG with a pool (i.e thecoin.pw)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Verge uses the Scrypt mining algorithm, not the SHA256d algorithm that your block erupter implements.